# Is it possible to tell Julia to interpret 0.0/0.0 as 1?

Tags: julia

I'm dealing with some Float64 functions that inside its body compute some fractions that can take the value 0.0/0.0. In that case, that value should be interpret as 1.0. Is it possible to do this automatically and avoid coding the pathological cases?

Comment: why don't you check for this case and do some conditionals for the numerator/denominator?

Comment: Right now I'm doing that but I thought there would be some package or global option that could do the trick for me.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess I will have to stay with these 'extra lines' of code. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why one can legitimately want to make a limited definition such that division works this way. It's obviously a poor default, but that's not what's being asked. I don't think commenting just for the sake of "don't do that" is really warranted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is fairly straightforward to do this in a safe way that doesn't break julia or other people's code.

One way to achieve this is either inside your module or at the REPL, before you ever explicitly use the `/` function[1], simply write

```
/(args...) = Base.:(/)(args...)

function /(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    if x == 0.0 && y == 0.0
        1.0
    else
        Base.:(/)(x, y)
    end 
end
```

At the repl:

```
julia> 1 / 2
0.5

julia> 10.0 / 0.0
Inf

julia> 0.0 / 0.0
1.0
```

What this does is *shadows* the built in `/` function and replaces it with your own custom version that falls back on the built-in one. This shadowing is local to only the current module you're in and won't leak outside unless someone explicitly asks for your version.

Another (perhaps preferable) option is to make a new infix division function via unicode operators. Here's an example:

```
function /̂(x, y) # /̂ is typed /\hat<TAB> at the REPL
    if x == 0 && y == 0
        one(promote_type(typeof(x), typeof(y)))
    else
        x / y
    end 
end
```

At the REPL:

```
julia> 0 /̂ 0.0
1.0

julia> 1 /̂ 2
0.5

julia> 0 / 0
NaN
```

This works because anytime you apply a unicode modifier like `\hat` or a superscript or whatever to an infix function symbol (like `/` or `*` or whatever) you make a new infix operator with the same precedence. This is nice because we get to keep the old `/` definition around and we have a visual marker on our division operator that something peculiar is happening.

Enjoy!

---

[1]: Functions from Base are only actually pulled into your namespace the first time you use them, so if you have not yet used `/` in your current scope, you are free to shadow it. Otherwise, you'll have to introduce a new scope via a `let` block and only have `/` shadowed there.

Comment: This is type piracy.

Comment: No it isn't. As defined here, `/` is a brand new function that sometimes calls `Base.:(/)`. As Mason says, it won't "leak" into other modules.

Comment: Might want to mention that if `Base.:(/)` has been broaght into scope, then you can't do this globaly,
but you can do it with a `let` block still

Comment: I said “... before you ever explicitly use the / function, simply write ...” but yeah, I could be more precise.

Comment: Added mention of let blocks and elaborated on when `/` is brought into the scope.

Comment: Thanks, @Mason. I appreciate the help.